# Negative z-index on div container preventing access to handlers. How can I work around this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index

I'm making a web site for a friend and the background is this partially opened curtain png, like a stage. The content of the site lies in between the left and right sides of the curtain. There is also a curtain draped across the top. Content scrolls up and down using divs as slides, where all 'slide' divs are wrapped in a 'slides' div. Scrolling up and down would normally have the slides scroll 'over' the draped curtain at the top, but I changed the z-index of the container to -1 so that the slides would slide 'underneath' the curtain.

But now since the -1 z-index forces the 'slides' underneath the main plane, the main plane is blocking any sort of clicking events that would normally occur - i.e. a button on a slide that would lead to other slides.

I'm not sure how to go about this problem. I need the -1 z-index on the container to keep the slides sliding underneath, but the main plane is preventing any clicking on those slides.

Any ideas?

```
.container {
  pointer-events: none;

 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
 }

 position: relative;
 background-image: url('../images/curtains.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-position: 0 -100px;

.slide {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 880px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: -1;
  pointer-events: none;

.content {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle of the problem by any chance? It's really hard to debug z-index issues with no code.

Comment: Why do you have `pointer-events: none` on the `.slide`?

Comment: Left over from something I was trying. I forgot to take it out. I took it out; it had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pointer-events:none` (css) to prevent the curtain from capturing your events.

If you need support for older browsers, you can hack your way by listening for mouse events on the curtain. When the curtain receives a mouse event, you hide the curtain and re-fire the event to reach the slides after which you show the curtain again.

Example: http://jsbin.com/iXiJUZi/1/edit

Comment: I wasn't able to get pointer-events: none to work on the .container div holding the curtains.png, because I think .container is the parent of the slides. Wouldn't that be also blocking the slides from capturing their events?

Comment: I would need to look at the HTML as well. Could you create a JsBin or some other easy way to test stuff?

Comment: I'll see if I can put together a jsbin or fiddle really quickly. Heck, if you're really curious the site's live -- pussycatrevue.com. It's a work in progress.